# Forward Sampling for HMM

Tags: inference, hidden-markov-model

Is it reasonable to use **forward sampling** to compute the probability of P(X_1=x_1, ..., X_N=x_n) in an HMM where is the observation variable?

Is the forward sampling algorithm related to the forward-algorithm for HMM?

Comment: Do you mean how to compute the probability of a sequence of possible latent states?  The forward algorithm conditions on the observations up to time $t$.

Comment: No I mean computing the probability of the sequence of observations (x1, x2, . . . , xN ) using forward sampling. I believe with forward sampling in HMM, the process is to simply generate multiple samples and then get the number of samples for which (X_1=x_1, ..., X_N=x_n) over all the samples, correct?

Comment: Hmmm, that would take a lot of simulations in order to get an accurate estimate of the probability.  Why do you want to sample as opposed to computing the probability directly?

Comment: I don't, I mainly wanted to know if the forward sampling for HMM some how simplifies to doing the forward algorithm or to any form?